# How to dynamically set foreign key in a eloquent model laravel and how to use it with withCount

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, model, laravel-9

i have a column name in a table like below

Table Code 1

| 34222X234X4422 | 34222X234X4423 | 34222X234X4424 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A15 | A15 |
| A1 | A6 | A7 |
| A3 | A3 | A3 |
| A3 | A3 | A7 |
| A5 | A15 | A8 |

Table Code 2

| ID | cid | Code | Desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4422 | A1 | desc 1 |
| 2 | 4423 | A2 | desc 2 |
| 3 | 4422 | A3 | desc 3 |
| 4 | 4424 | A4 | desc 4 |

and so on

I want to count how many record from table Code 2 are exist in table Code 1 column 34222X234X4422, 34222X234X4423, 34222X234X4424 depend on Code_2.cid using Eloquent Laravel withCount.

I am thinking of using Model Relation one-to-many, but the foreign key cannot be static.
Is it possible to passing parameter from controller to model relationship and how to input it in the withCount?

I am trying this:

```
class Code_2 extends Model
{
public function unit($id)
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Code_1::class, $id, 'code);
    }
}
```

here is my controller

```
$column = '34222X234X4424';
$detail1 = Code_2::withCount(['unit => function(Builder $query) use ($column){
            $query->on('code_1.'.$column, '=', 'code_2.code');
        },])->get(['id', 'code', 'decs']);
```

Turn out to be error "Too few arguments to function App\Models\Code_2::unit()".

How can i fix this?

Thank you.

Note: I cannot change the database at all. Just view it only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a variable in model and pass value for it same as :

Model :

```
class Code_2 extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'code_2';
    protected $field;
    public function __construct($field = 'code_2_id')
    {
        $this->field = $field;
    }

    public function unit()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Code_1::class, $this->field, 'Code');
    }
}
```

And Controller you can use :

```
$column = '34222X234X4424';
$model = new Code2($column);
$detail1 = $model->withCount('unit')->get(['id', 'code', 'decs']);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for me! The method you suggests are never crossed my mind before.

Answer (score 0):

you can't pass parametrized relations in `with` or `withCount` so i'd suggest to define 3 relations

```php
// Code_2 model

  public static $toCountRelations = [
    'x22',
    'x23',
    'x24'
  ];

  public function x22()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Code_1::class, '34222X234X4422', 'Code');
  }

  public function x23()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Code_1::class, '34222X234X4423', 'Code');
  }

  public function x24()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Code_1::class, '34222X234X4424', 'Code');
  }

  /**
   * note that this function will return 0 if no of above relations is loaded
   *
   * @return int
   */
  public function getCodesCountAttribute()
  {
    $sum = 0;
    foreach (self::$toCountRelations as $relation)
      if ($this->relationLoaded($relation)) {
      // this syntax for $relation = 'x22' will get value of 
      // $this->x22_count
        $sum += $this->{$relation . '_count'};
      }
    return $sum;
  }

  // controller
  $detailed = Code_2::withCount(Code_2::$toCountRelations)->get(['id', 'Code', 'Desc']);
```

at this step you have collection of models with values of `x22_count`, `x23_count`, `x24_count` and computed property `codes_count` returning global count of **loaded** relations so if in future columns list will change you can simply change `$toCountRelations` array with required relations